# SSH into Raspberry Pi times out, but pinging works

Tags: ssh

I followed [this](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address) tutorial on how to setup a static ip on my Raspberry Pi.

I can now successfully ping my Raspberry Pi from my Mac, but when I try to ssh like so:

```
ping [ip]
sudo ssh pi@[ip]
```

I get the error:

```
ssh: connect to host [ip] port 22: Operation timed out
```

Looking at similar questions I noticed them saying things about port forwarding.  I don't have access to my apartments router or anything, but shouldn't I still be able to do it locally then?

Comment: are you sure there's SSHD running on your Pi? what distribution are you using? you may connect TV/keyboard to check and amend your configuration to allow sshd to run.

Comment: the range `192.x.x.x`  is a private range and not used on the internet. You would need a static IP on your Internet or use DynDNS like I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you setup a static IP on your Pi you will still need to [forward the default port 22](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/how-do-i-make-my-raspberry-pi-webserver-public/7209#7209) to the Pi, on your Router.

After you have forwarded it you will then need to know the IP of your home internet connection. Most of the time they are dynamic and change as defined by the ISP. You can overcome this by setting up dynamic dns on the Pi.

My favuoritre free DynDNS provider is no-ip but any one will work the same. Install the client to update your IP to the DNS record.

```
sudo apt-get install ddclient
```

Then go and edit the configuration file .

```
#
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf
daemon=60                          # check every 60 seconds
syslog=yes                         # log update msgs to syslog
mail=root                          # mail all msgs to root
mail-failure=root                  # mail failed update msgs to root
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid          # record PID in file.
ssl=yes                            # use ssl-support.
use=web, web=dynupdate.no-ip.com   # get ip from server.
server=pi.no-ip.org                # Your DNS
login=                   # your login
password=                # your password
server=www.no-ip.com,    \
protocol=dyndns2          \
YOUR-DOMAIN
```

Then at work or anywhere else in the world you can connect to your Pi over ssh using the DNS you have selected.

```
sudo ssh pi@[mypi.no-ip.org]
```

Comment: I don't have access to my router directly, because I live in an apartment complex.  I can't setup portforwarding because resources like portforwarding.com require a lot of information on it.

Comment: That makes it allot more complicated then. Doing it easily will not work then. You will need a server on the internet and then create a SSH Reverse tunnel and it become pretty complicated. Without router access there is not much you can do without complex solutions

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10422/remote-desktop-connection-to-raspberry-pi-without-specifying-a-port/10428#10428 - You can read that on how to reverse tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me too, try

> ssh pi@raspberrypi.local

if the hostname of your **Pi** is *raspberrypi* or replace it with the hostname of your **Pi**.

Comment: This happened like 6 years ago

Comment: @TMP :P sorry, I am new here was just looking around.